# JFileChooser.getSelectedFile() return null when implement custom action button

Tags: java, swing, action, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I have a `JFrame` with `JFileChooser`. There is need to have a custom import button instead of default file chooser action button.

If i use custom action button, `JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()` return null if i enter value in File Name textbox. Whereas if i click the file and click custom import, i can get the file which i chosen.

Here i included the sample code to reproduce this

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FileChooserDemo extends JPanel
                             implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JFileChooser importFileChooser;
    JFrame frame;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("FileChooserDemo");

        JPanel inputJobDetailsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,5));

        importFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        importFileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
        importFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        importFileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        inputJobDetailsPanel.add(importFileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        GridBagLayout importButtonPanelLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        importButtonPanelLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {150};
        importButtonPanelLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {30};

        JPanel importButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        importButtonPanel.setLayout(importButtonPanelLayout);

        JButton importButton = new JButton("Custom Import");
        importButton.setActionCommand("import");
        importButton.addActionListener(this);
        importButtonPanel.add(importButton, new GridBagConstraints());

        JButton OtherButton = new JButton("Other Action");
        OtherButton.setActionCommand("otherImport");
        OtherButton.addActionListener(this);
        importButtonPanel.add(OtherButton, new GridBagConstraints());

        inputJobDetailsPanel.add(importButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.add(inputJobDetailsPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FileChooserDemo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("import")) {
            if(importFileChooser.getSelectedFile() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You entered file name but getSelectedFile() return null");
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Chosen File Name: " + importFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
            }
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You clicked other action");
        }

    }
}
```

O/P:

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the application
2. Enter a valid file name in "File Name" text box
3. Click Custom Import
4. Now you can see "You entered file name but getSelectedFile() return null"

Note: If i enabled default action button by using  `importFileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(true);`

I can get the getSelectedFile() even i entered in textbox without clicking on the file.

Actually i am trying to write an automation script, so i can enter only file path via "File Name" Text box.

Any idea to get the files by getSelectedFile() without clicking on the file??

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Mac OS X; chooser UI has no "text box."

Comment: @trashgod : Here i included the screen shot. I can see like that in both Windows as well as Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the output as expected. Invoking default file chooser button action listener

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command.equals("import")) {
        if(importFileChooser.getSelectedFile() == null) {
            MetalFileChooserUI ui = (MetalFileChooserUI) importFileChooser.getUI();
            for(ActionListener a: ui.getDefaultButton(importFileChooser).getActionListeners()) {
                a.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null) {
                          //Nothing need go here, the actionPerformed method (with the above arguments) will trigger the respective listener
                  });
            }
        }

        if(importFileChooser.getSelectedFile() != null) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Chosen File Name: " + importFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You entered file name but getSelectedFile() return null");
        }
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You clicked other action");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not unreasonable, although I've prefer an accessory. Some limitations are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38566916/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Because not all Look & Feel implementations provide for direct entry of a file name in a text field<sup>*</sup>, you may want to consider an alternate design:

- Less modal: As shown in [*Providing an Accessory Component*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory), you can add an accessory component in a panel "with more controls on it such as checkboxes that toggle between features." The exact details would depend on the features enabled by <kbd>Custom Import</kbd> and <kbd>Other Action</kbd>.
- More modal: Present a modal dialog of choices *after* the user has approved a particular section.

The intermediate approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38613969/230513) has the following limitations:

1. Assumes `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`.
2. [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html): "An unspecified behavior will be caused if the `id` parameter of any particular `ActionEvent` instance is not in the range from `ACTION_FIRST` to `ACTION_LAST`.
3. [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#ActionEvent-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.String-int-): "A `null` command string is legal, but not recommended."

<sup>* e.g. `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. But I cannot get your point. Should i need to change the LookAndFeel?

Comment: I don't think that will help; instead, move toward an accessory component or a modal dialog.

Comment: I have posted my answer, can you please validate and let me know if this causes any other issues. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Tamil: I've elaborated above.